# convert from imageproc module image of rasbperry pi into ( numpy array or cvmat )

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

imageproc module in rasbperry pi is very efficient but i couldn't use opencv with it
due to the different type of image related to imageproc module.

So , i seek for a method to enable using opencv of image type( cvmat for cv , numpyarray for cv2 , .. ) with the rasbperry pi imageproc module
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to convert the `imgproc` output to a `numpy.array`. After that you can use the array with `cv2` almost directly.

If we assume you have your `imgproc` image in `img`, then:

```
import numpy

img_array = numpy.array([ [ img[x,y] for x in range(img.width) ] for y in range(img.height) ] , dtype='uint8')
```

Unfortunately, there are no faster data access methods in `imgproc`, you will have to do it one-by-one. But after this slowish looping you can use `img_array` directly with `cv2`.

---

If this crashes (it shouldn't) with a segfault (it really shouldn't) something goes badly wrong probably in `imgproc`. The best guess is that `img[x,y]` points to outside of the image created by `imgproc`. To debug this, let's split the command into more palatable parts.

```
# dimensions ok?
w = img.width
h = img.height
print w,h

# can we fetch pixels at the extremes?
upperleft = img[0,0]
lowerright = img[w-1, h-1]
print upperleft, lowerright

# the loop without conversion to array
img_l = [ [ img[x,y] for x in range(w) ] for y in range(h) ]
print len(img_l)

# convert the image into an array
img_array = numpy.array(img_l, dtype='uint8')
print img_array.shape
```

Where does this crash? Note that the `print` statement is not entirely reliable with segfaults on all platforms, but it indicates that the code has run at least that far.

If the code crashes when accessing `img` dimensions or pixels, the problem may be in the image capture code. If you show a minimal example in the question, the problem is easier to debug.

Comment: That is interesting. Where does it crash? If you remove the line above (`img_array = ...`) from your code, does it still crash? Have you verified your OpenCV works as it should? It'll help if you edit your question so that it has a minimal example of the crashing code.

Comment: If i remove this line , it will not crash
And i am sure that opencv works as it should
So what can i do ??
Thanks